# Unclosed WCF calls begin failing after 2 minutes after TLS 1.2 update - ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol is changing

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0, windows-services, tls1.2

I have a .NET Windows service running that has a thread that calls a WCF service using a `wsHttpBinding` with `TransportWithMessageCredential` security. We recently moved the WCF server and it now supports only TLS 1.2 and have updated the Windows Service client to force TLS 1.2 (since it's .NET 4.0) using `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;`

The Windows Service thread calls the WCF service in a do...while loop every 2 hours.

```
do
{
    GetUpdates();
}
while (!_syncEvents.ExitThreadEvent.WaitOne(_interval, true));
```

...

```
private void GetUpdates()
{
    MerchantProcessingClient svc = new MerchantProcessingClient();

    try
    {
        int lastProcessedBatch = facility.GetLastBatchRetrieved();

        bool alreadyProcessedMostRecentBatch = svc.IsFacilitysMostRecentBatch(_facilityID, lastProcessedBatch);

        if (!alreadyProcessedMostRecentBatch)
        {
            MPResultOfSettledPaymentsResult mpResult = svc.GetSettledPayments2(_facilityID, lastProcessedBatch);

            //Continues to process the response - never calls svc.Close()
```

When the windows service starts up, the WCF calls execute without error, but the next time it runs after the 2 hour interval and every time after that, it gets the following exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://example.org/MerchantProcessing.svc. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
  at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.DoOperation(SecuritySessionOperation operation, EndpointAddress target, Uri via, SecurityToken currentToken, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.GetTokenCore(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenProvider.GetToken(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.ClientSecuritySessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Data.MerchantProcessingService.IMerchantProcessing.IsFacilitysMostRecentBatch(Guid facilityID, Int32 facilityBatchHistoryID)
   at WindowsService.ProcessMerchantServices.GetUpdates()
```

If we update the interval to call the service every 60 seconds instead of every 2 hours, no exception is logged after about 10 minutes. If we change it to 120 seconds, it does get the exception on the 2nd try.

So it seems that something is holding on to a security token or trying to reuse a connection or something and if it doesn't do that within in some interval less than 2 minutes it expires. The server's `receivetimeout` is set to 90 seconds so I kind of suspect that is the limit. We already had an update waiting to go out that calls `svc.Close` on the WCF proxy, but what I don't understand is how or where something's being persisted when a new `MerchantProcessingClient` is created in each iteration. I'm also not sure why we aren't seeing this in the windows service's sister WPF application which uses the same `Data.MerchantProcessingService.IMerchantProcessing` proxy to call the service. What is happening here?

---

**Update:**

Narrowed it down a bit more but am still confused. I've ruled out the server's `receiveTimeout` - that's not involved. I added the following logging to the Windows service:

```
logger.Debug("ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = " + (int)System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol);

bool alreadyProcessedMostRecentBatch = svc.IsFacilitysMostRecentBatch(_facilityID, lastProcessedBatch);
```

and watched the traffic to our WCF server in Wireshark while this ran. Wireshark shows the first call using Tls 1.2 and the second call that fails using Tls v1! So that explains the exception because the server does not support v1. Before the first call above logging logs:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 240    //Ssl3 & Tls
```

So my `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;` line in my application `Settings` class in the class library containing `MerchantProcessingClient` is either not applied or got overwritten by this point, I'm assuming the latter. Ok, but then how is the first call using Tls 1.2 anyway?? `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` is overridden by something and only the first time?

Then before the 2nd call the log shows this:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 192    //Tls
```

I then tried setting the `SecurityProtocol` just before each service call like this:

```
logger.Debug("ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = " + (int)System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol);

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (System.Net.SecurityProtocolType)3072;

logger.Debug("New ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = " + (int)System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol);

bool alreadyProcessedMostRecentBatch = svc.IsFacilitysMostRecentBatch(_facilityID, lastProcessedBatch);
```

This eliminates the exception, but the log over the first two iterations is what's interesting:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 192
New ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 3072
/* service call succeeds here, Wireshark shows Tls 1.2 */

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 192
New ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 3072
/* 2nd service call succeeds here, Wireshark shows Tls 1.2 */
```

On the 2nd iteration, `SecurityProtocol` is set back to 192 again! Something else, that I'm 95% sure isn't our code explicitly, is changing the `SecurityProtocol` back to `Tls` v1. Other threads in this Windows Service are calling a different WCF service, that may not support Tls 1.2, in parallel on their own intervals so I thought maybe it was internally automatically downgrading the `SecurityProtocol` when it calls those services, but that doesn't explain how the first call has always succeeded or how all calls in the original code succeed when setting the interval to 1 minute instead of 2. I am baffled. Our current plan is to upgrade to .NET 4.6.2 ASAP, but still trying to figure this out. Too many unknowns.

Comment: Regarding the rollback, my advice here is "don't beg". It is counterproductive, from your perspective of wanting an answer.

Comment: I was going to add a link earlier, and then was distracted with work. It's about how language reflecting confidence can improve one's chances of an answer (or, conversely, how language that pleads and asks for sympathy can reduce it). [The discussion is here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions).

Comment: Are these propertise/Method useful? MaxServicePointIdleTime,SetTcpKeepAlive.